# What tool in Word most productively can replace text in templates?

Tags: microsoft-word

At the charity where I volunteer, I sometimes must update contract templates where multiple fields appear, like for the date, counterparty's name, etc.

I don't think I need Mail Merge because this template is updated yearly, and there are few recipients. Here are my requirements:

1. The fields to be updated must appear in a different color and typeface.
2. There must be a list exhibiting all such fields in the lengthy document so that I don't overlook fields. It's unquestionably too unproductive to scroll through the document to double-check every field!

Comment: have you tried the search + replace function?

Comment: @swift_Dan Yes, but that function doesn't guarantee 1 and 2.

Comment: How are the 'fields' denoted in the templates? With bookmarks, special formatting, merge fields?

Comment: @BorislavIvanov I just used text for now, but advise me if I ought denote them in other ways!

Comment: Is it about updating the template for contracts or actual contracts themselves? As e.g. counterparty's name would either be "counterpartyname" or "John Smith". Do you have a list of said properties? Are they arbitrary? If every instance of counterparty name is marked as such replacing the definition of counterparty name is sufficient. Which is also why Mail Merge would be something to consider. But this requires e.g. the contracts themselves to be based on a common template to make sense.

Comment: You could transform the Word document into a fillable form. See [6 Simple Steps to Create a Form in Word](https://pdf.wondershare.com/word/create-a-form-in-word.html). The Tab key will move the focus from one field to the next so you don't need a list to examine all fields.

Answer (score 2):

In Word, the tool that lets one create document templates is using forms with
fillable fields. This feature can ensure tabbing through all the fields in order
by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and also (if required) protecting the
non-fillable text against modifications.

When a form is being used, the information entered into a field is assigned
a bookmark name. Through the use of other bookmark-related fields, you may then
reference the field elsewhere in the document, thus duplicating its content
elsewhere in more than one place.

The Developer Tab is used when creating the form.
With it one creates fillable fields, but also other content controls
such as drop-down lists. As this is a Word document, VBA macros can enhance
its functionality to make it a sophisticated rich document.

For more details, see these references (but many more can be found):

- [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b)
- [Working with Form Fields](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008303_Working_with_Form_Fields.html)
- [How to Create a Template You Can Type & Tab Through](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-a-template-you-can-type-tab-through)
- [Creating Fillable Forms Using Microsoft Word](https://www.itsolutions-inc.com/news-and-training/article/how-to-create-fillable-forms-in-microsoft-word/)